# Finding paths in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have a two-dimensional array of integers and want to find the path with the lowest sum from the left column to the right column, when going up, down and left is possible. I started with a `loop` of all rows and tried to build up the paths as lists.

```
(defparameter *test-array*
  #2A((131 673 234 103 18)
      (201 96 342 965 150)
      (630 803 746 422 111)
      (537 699 497 121 956)
      (805 732 524 37 331)))

(defun find-paths (array &aux (height (array-dimension array 0)) (width (array-dimension array 1)))
  "Returns the possible paths across a given 2d array from the left column to
  the right column."
  (loop :for i :from 0 :below height
        ;; We have three ways per starting point up, left and down.
        ;; In the first and last row there are two ways, only.
        :append (loop :for (j l) :in '((1 0) (0 1) (-1 0))
                       :when (and (>= (+ j i) 0) (< (+ j i) height))
                         :collect (list (aref array i 0) (aref array (+ i j) l))) :into paths
        :finally (return paths)))
```

I was wondering if this really leads to a good solution. I am afraid that it will get more and more complex and memory comsuming to turn the whole array in a list of lists representing all possible paths. As far as I understand, it is a graph, basically. But how could I create the graph from the array without wasting memory?

Comment: How do you get from the left side to the right side, without being able to move to the right?

Comment: Ohh, I just stopped before implementing this because I found it too complex and wanted to ask first. Sorry, I was not clear enough in my description.

Comment: For reference: this is Project Euler problem 82.  I used A* and it worked fine.

Comment: @SteveLosh You are right, I didn’t want to spoil a possible solution. How did you manage the path generation?

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Split the problem into two parts. First write a generic `A*` function that takes a start state, a function to generate neighbor states, a goal predicate, etc, and returns the shortest path.  Section 6.4 of [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](https://github.com/norvig/paip-lisp#the-book) is a good overview of how to do this.  Then, use that `A*` function to solve the Euler problem by creating the necessary `goalp`, `neighbors`, etc functions that work with the array.  As a bonus the `A*` function will also help you solve other Euler problems.

Comment: Great, I had PAIP on my re-reading list anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems solvable by dynamic programming.

I'd create a new array with the same dimensions, which holds two values at each coordinate: the best path to it, and its cost.  Initialize these values at the leftmost column, then propagate them all the way to the right.

Then, propagate each element path up as far as it is an improvement.  Then left, then down.  Cycle through the directions until none of them gives an improvement.

Finally, the best path at the rightmost column is the solution.